# how to redeploy application using management console in jboss EAP 6.3.0 GA?

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am using `JBOSS EAP 6.3.0`, I want to `redeploy` my `application` using management console. I don't see `redeploy` or `enable/disable` or `refresh` option under below section

```
Runtime>>Manage Deployments
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
The question was related to domain mode. See comments.

ORIGINAL:
The section you mention is correct. You can try different browser as I see no issues as you can check in
[image: this screenshot]

If you want an alternative you can use jboss-cli.sh (.bat) for this purpose:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command="/deployment=DEPLOYMENT_NAME:redeploy"
```

or interactive mode

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c
> /deployment= [you can use tab to get deployment-name hints] 
> /deployment=DEPLOYMENT_NAME:redeploy
```

Comment: I don't see Ena/Disable button , can you please see image i have added in question? it shows only Add, Remove, Assign, Replace

Comment: I haven't noticed that you run EAP in domain mode. For this mode, it is important to note, that deployments are bound to server-groups. Thus you have to manage your deployment for desired server group.
So you have to switch to the SERVER GROUPS tab pick your server group, click view and there you should see the en/disable button. Also notice, that you have to select the correct server group.

Comment: Thanks, it's working, can i restart server from web admin console?